# How to implement Code coverage (gcov) with Bazel

Tags: code-coverage, bazel

I am starting to work with bazel, My current aim is to implement code coverage with bazel. Could you please share any examples or documentation for the same?

Answer (score 2):

```
bazel coverage
```

will do the job. The coverage command line argument generates code coverage report for specified test targets

Example

```
  bazel coverage -s \                                         
    --instrument_test_targets \
    --experimental_cc_coverage \
    --combined_report=lcov \
    --coverage_report_generator=@bazel_tools//tools/test/CoverageOutputGenerator/java/com/google/devtools/coverageoutputgenerator:Main \
    //...
```

HTML Output:

```
  genhtml /home/vertexwahn/.cache/bazel/_bazel_vertexwahn/e74a825d0eb0c2db4b6f8afd819b274c/execroot/__main__/bazel-out/k8-fastbuild/testlogs/foo_test/coverage.dat --output-directory coverage
```